# Marca d'água (watermark) no rotativa PDF em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, relatório

Olá, estou com dificuldades para adicionar uma marca d'água em um relatório gerado com rotativa pdf.

Este relatório tem um cabeçalho, que se repete em todas as páginas e um rodapé que também se repete em todas as páginas, agora estou querendo fazer com que tenha uma marca d-água de fundo em todas as páginas, os resultados que obtive até o momento foi:

1) a marca em cima dos dados impressos, repetindo em todas as páginas tentei utilizar position relative, absolute e fixed, com z-index, mas não funcionou conforme eu gostaria, parte do relatório ficou com marca behind(embaixo) e outra parte ficou (In Front).

2) a marca abaixo dos dados repetindo em todas as páginas conforme o resultado que gostaria, mas isso somente na primeira página, na segunda página a marca saiu impressa mais para a esquerda do relatório repetindo parte da imagem no lado direito.

```css
.water_mark {
    background-image: url(../Images/marca-dagua.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    padding-right:5px; background-size: 80% auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding-left water_mark" style="">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
    </table>
    </div>
```

```css
.water_mark {
    background-image: url(../Images/marca-dagua.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    padding-right:5px; background-size: 80% auto;
    background-position-x: 100px;
}
```

este é o código do resultado 2.

```css
.water_mark {
    background-image: url(../Images/marca-dagua.png);
    width: 100%;
  height: 1500px; /* TAMANHO DA FOLHA */
  Position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; /* TENTEI OUTROS Z-INDEX */  
}
```

```html
<div class="water_mark" style="">
</div>
   <table class="table table-bordered">
     </table>
```

código do resultado 1.

Eu acredito que tenha uma forma de passar para o Rotativa PDF uma imagem de fundo, mas até o momento não consegui o resultado, por este motivo tentei resolver com css.

OBS: o cabeçalho e o rodapé são feitos com o rotativa através da propriedade:
CustomSwitches conforme código a seguir.

```
string customSwitches = "--footer-left \"Versão: " + Versao.NumeroVersao + "\" " +
                    "--footer-center \"Chave de segurança: " + ChaveSeguranca + "\" " +
                    "--footer-right \"Página: [page] de [toPage]\"" +
                    " --footer-line --footer-font-size \"7\" " +
                    " --footer-spacing 5 " +
                    "--header-html  \"" + Url.Action("Header", "PadraoRelatorio", new { area = "", Titulo = "PARA CONSTRUÇÃO" }, "http") + "\" " +
                    "--header-spacing \"5\" " +
                    "--header-font-size \"7\"";
```

Comment: O Rotativa é bem limitado pra fazer isso que você quer. Recomendo partir para o [PdfSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) ou ainda o [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

Comment: Cigano, agradeço sua resposta, entendo que Rotativa é realmente limitada, estarei fazendo a migração para outro relatório futuramente, (possivelmente para iTextSharp), mas no momento preciso dar uma resposta rápida ao cliente, este caso da marca d'agua foi uma adição de requisitos, e infelizmente não conseguimos prever isto, então tenho um prazo extremamente curto.

Comment: Avise que não dá pra fazer rápido. Veja: o Rotativa converte HTML em marca d'água. HTML já não é algo que tem "marca d'água", então você tem que formatar o PDF na mão.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, estou refazendo o relatório com iTextSharp. As ferramentas do telerik e XtraReport(devexpress), são boas? já trabalhou com alguma?

Comment: Não, não pago por componente algum que uso nas minhas aplicações.